# Best Settings for Html purify

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

I would like to use [**PHP-based tool HTML Purifier**](http://htmlpurifier.org/) on a textbox to prevent xss but I would like to allow the following:

1. basic tags like `<b>`,`<i>`,`<u>`
2. links
3. images

I would like to block all CSS and JavaScript. I just tried HTML Purifier and it failed on this case. Just see [this example](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5bAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.Linkify%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.PurifierLinkify.DocURL%5d=%23%25s&filter%5bAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp.Exceptions%5d=td%0D%0Ath&filter%5bAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5d=0&filter%5bNull_CSS.AllowedProperties%5d=1&filter%5bCore.CollectErrors%5d=0&filter%5bNull_HTML.Allowed%5d=1&filter%5bNull_HTML.Doctype%5d=1&filter%5bHTML.TidyLevel%5d=medium&filter%5bURI.DisableExternalResources%5d=0&filter%5bNull_URI.Munge%5d=1&html=%3Cb%3EInline+%3Cdel%3Econtext+%3Cdiv%3ENo+block+allowed+%3Cgreat+going+%3C/div%3E%3C/del%3E%3C/b%3E&submit=Submit). How can I take care of this?

Also I would want all words of the form `#abcd` and `@abcd` to be replaced with custom html *(as you would have guessed it a link)*. Is it possible with this or do I have to do my own replace?

Comment: Define "Failed". Swallowing everything after `<` is not exactly nice, but it's not a security problem, either

Comment: but it's something like  false positive

Comment: but why, what's the problem with it exactly? How can that be used to smuggle evil content onto your site?

Comment: not to smiggle evil content but some perfectly valid content is lost

Answer (score 4):

Set HTML.Allowed to something like `b,i,u,a[href],img[src|alt]`

See [here](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5bAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.Linkify%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.PurifierLinkify.DocURL%5d=%23%25s&filter%5bAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp.Exceptions%5d=td%0D%0Ath&filter%5bAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5d=0&filter%5bNull_CSS.AllowedProperties%5d=1&filter%5bCore.CollectErrors%5d=0&filter%5bHTML.Allowed%5d=b,i,u,a%5bhref%5d,img%5bsrc|alt%5d&filter%5bNull_HTML.Doctype%5d=1&filter%5bHTML.TidyLevel%5d=medium&filter%5bURI.DisableExternalResources%5d=0&filter%5bNull_URI.Munge%5d=1&html=%3Cb%3EInline+%3Cdel%3Econtext+%3Cdiv%3ENo+block+allowed+%3Cgreat+going+%3C/div%3E%3C/del%3E%3C/b%3E&submit=Submit).

Comment: Please expand URL shortened link.

Answer (score -2):

Regular expressions and e modifier

```
function checkTag( $tag ) {
  $tag = removeslashes( $tag );

  ...

  return $secureTag;
}

$html = preg_replace( "/<[^>]+>/e", " checkTag( '\$0' )", $input );
```

Comment: i asked about best settings for html purifier

Answer (score -2):

PHP has a built-in function that seems to do exactly what you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

It even has a whitelist feature so it can allow some tags.

For the `#abcd` and the `@abcd` part I think you will have to use a `preg_replace()` for that. I have used a similar function and it does the `@abcd` part very well :).

```
$sClickText = preg_replace("/\@([a-zA-Z0-9_])+/",' <a href="#reply" onClick="reply(\'' . "$0" . '\')">' . "$0" . '</a>',$sInputText);
```

Comment: Allowable tags are bit unsecure - because attacer can put onclick, ommouseover parameter there sucessfully

Comment: `strip_tags` alone is not considered enough against XSS, though.

Comment: i asked about best settings for html purifier